# curl is not operable because of some missing dependecies

Tags: magento-1.9, curl

Anybody know what it means this error message? And how to solve it?
We want to install an extension for Full Page Cache in our Magento Store version 1.9.3.
We use Apache Debian 9 for our server.

[image]